# FlutterError (Unable to load asset: assets/chat1 .txt)

Tags: flutter, assets

I know I placed my text file at the location assets\chat1.txt, and my code also works with other txts but somehow I always get the following error:

> Exception has occurred.
>
> FlutterError (Unable to load asset: assets/chat1.txt)

my Code:

```
Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
  }
```

pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

Comment: are your assets folder under your folder lib or the project folder?

Comment: in the folder under my main project folder

Comment: should I put it in the lib folder?

Answer (score 0):

Add the full path in pubspec.yaml file and you should consider the indentation for assets:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/chat1.txt
```

Comment: doesn't assets/ already automatically include assets/chat1.txt?